# NodeJS/Puppeteer - Click on div by title?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

I have to click the `div` with `title="Lista de Chamados"`. I've tried several different ways, but nothing works. The `div` is draggable, so the last solution wouldn't solve it (and it does NOT work).

How can I click on `div title="Lista de Tarefas"` (independently of its position)?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const URL = 'https://dummy.br/'

    await page.goto(URL, {waitUntil: 'load'});
    console.log(page.url());

    const SELETOR_USUARIO = '#usuario';
    const SELETOR_SENHA = '#senha';
    const usuario = 'usr';
    const senha = 'pass';

    await page.type(SELETOR_USUARIO, usuario);
    await page.type(SELETOR_SENHA, senha);

    //console.log(page.url());

    //FAZ LOGIN:
    page.click('#login'),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });


    //browser.close();
};

scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value); 
});
```

**--EDIT**

```
...
    //FAZ LOGIN:
    await page.click('#login'),
    //await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }) //espera nova página carregar


    await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

    //await page.click('div[title="Lista de Tarefas"]'); //Error: No node found for selector: div[title="Lista de Tarefas"]

/*  const seletor = 'div[title="Lista de Tarefas"]';
    const botao = await page.$(seletor);
    console.log(botao); //null
    botao.click(); */

    const botao = await page.evaluate( () => {
        let b = document.querySelector('div[title="Lista de Tarefas"]');
        console.log('in>>> ' + b); // b and b[0] are NULL
    });
```

This is the code to the element I need to click:

```
 <div class="menu-lateral-contraido-sub-container" title="Lista de Chamados" draggable="true" style="opacity: 1;">
       <div to="/main/listachamado/" class="route-redirect-box">
          <div class="menu-lateral-item-contraido-container cor-tema-topo-fundo ">
             <div class="menu-lateral-item-contraido-icon"><i class="ellevo-icons">lista_chamado</i></div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: await page.$(selector, option)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), `[title=""]`, inside [`page.click()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options) to click on an element by title:

```
await page.click('div[title="Lista de Tarefas"]');
```

Comment: @tramada In regards to your edit, [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which resolves to an [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) array. This means that you will need to specify the `ElementHandle` by index with which you want to `focus()` or `click()`.

Comment: @tramada Also, [`elementHandle.focus()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlefocus) and [`elementHandle.click()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleclickoptions) both return Promises, so make sure you are using the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator with those two functions.

Comment: I can't use page.click cause there is no node for selector, and is still not working with waitForNavigation. I just can't click it